# Setting timeout in smtplib

Tags: python, python-3.7, smtplib

How can I set a timeout for a gmail server in `smtplib.SMTP()`?

My code:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com" ,587)
smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com" ,587)
```

Comment: `server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com" ,587, timeout=60)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/smtplib.html) you can set the `timeout` parameter value in the call, such as:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=60)
```